# Process Exit: value 3221225477

Tags: c++, pointers

When I am adding

> `local_w_p_n->wp_val_p = rx_pbuf;`
> `local_w_p_n->wp_val_n = rx_netif;`

in `rx_local_p_n` function to the program code, the code is compiled but running in *Process Exit: value 3221225477*. Does anyone know why and how to fix it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct pbuf{
    int a;
    int b;
};

struct netif{
    int c;
    int d;
};

struct wrapper_p_n{ // wrapper for pbuf- and netif-struct pointer
    struct pbuf *wp_val_p;
    struct netif *wp_val_n;
};

void rx_local_p_n(struct pbuf *rx_pbuf, struct netif *rx_netif)
{
    // wrap the received pointer
    
    struct wrapper_p_n *local_w_p_n;
    
    local_w_p_n->wp_val_p = rx_pbuf;
    local_w_p_n->wp_val_n = rx_netif;
    
    printf("rx_local_p_n\n");
    
    //Passing *local_w_p_n pointer to another function 
    //check_value(local_w_p_n);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    
    // give values to local_pbuf and netif
    struct pbuf local_pbuf;
    local_pbuf.a = 1;
    local_pbuf.b = 2;
    
    struct netif local_netif;
    local_netif.c = 3;
    local_netif.d = 4;
    
    //passing pbuf- and netif-stuct to function
    rx_local_p_n(&local_pbuf, &local_netif);
    
    printf("return\n");
        
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: Where do you think your `local_w_p_n` variable points to?

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings if you haven't already, and read the warnings your compiler produces.

Comment: FWIW, 3221225477 in hex is `0xC0000005` which is the Win32 code for _segmentation fault_.

Comment: Why is `local_w_p_n` a pointer? You know about the address-of operator `&`, why not use it when and if needed?

Comment: Unrelated: You don't need to write `struct ...` when declaring variables. The name is `typedef`ined automatically so `wrapper_p_n* local_w_p_n;` is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
struct wrapper_p_n *local_w_p_n;

local_w_p_n->wp_val_p = rx_pbuf;
local_w_p_n->wp_val_n = rx_netif;
```

`local_w_p_n` is an uninitalised pointer, and dereferencing it is liable to cause your program to crash.

Judging by the commented out code, what you are really looking for is this

```
struct wrapper_p_n local_w_p_n;

local_w_p_n.wp_val_p = rx_pbuf;
local_w_p_n.wp_val_n = rx_netif;

//Passing pointer to local_w_p_n to another function 
check_value(&local_w_p_n);
```

Instead of declaring a pointer, the code above declares a regular variable, and then uses the address-of operator `&` to obtain a pointer to that variable.

In fact you wrote exactly the same code in `main`, so not sure why you tried something different here.